# Angular HttpClient with timeout seems do nothing

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

This is how I'm doing my requests (and it's working).

```
this.http
  .get(url, options)
  .pipe(retryWhen((errors) => this.retry(errors, { delay: retryDelay, take: retryTake })))
  .toPromise()
  .catch((ex) => {
    this.exception(ex);
    throw ex;
  });
```

Now, I have a specific address that takes too long to respond and because of that I'm getting 504.

So I'm trying work with `timeout` but it seems nothing changes, like on Chrome it waits only for 1 minute max. Heres the code:

```
this.http
  .get(`${this.host}/${action}${query}`, options)
  .pipe(timeout(300000), (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    return of(null);
  })
  .pipe(retryWhen((errors) => this.retry(errors, { delay: retryDelay, take: retryTake })))
  .toPromise()
  .catch((ex) => {
    this.exception(ex);
    throw ex;
  });
```

What could I be doing wrong?

**Working with:**

Angular 6.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [takeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html) method instead of timeout

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

//after 30 seconds, stop retrying
const timer$ = timer(30000);

this.http
  .get(url, options)
  .pipe(retryWhen((errors) => this.retry(errors, { delay: retryDelay, take: retryTake })),
        takeUntil(timer$))
  .toPromise()
  .catch((ex) => {
    this.exception(ex);
    throw ex;
  });
```

Comment: same thing, could that be a browser issue?

Comment: Not sure!! Ok try this one, move `takeUntil(timer$))` down the order. Updated answer.

Comment: same, only 1 minute on firefox and chrome